# Can we calculate this limit analytically?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

What will be the limit of the following for $x=0$?

$\sin(\cos(\tan(\sin(\cos(\tan(\sin(\cos(\tan( ... \mbox{infinite times} ... \sin(\cos(\tan(x)))))))...)$

On a calculator it seems to approach 0.72063..., but how do I get the answer analytically?

Comment: Could you clarify what infinite sequence you are considering?  Is the last operation always $\tan$?  Are you considering $n$ blocks of $\sin(\cos(\tan(...)))$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Its the block sin(cos(tan(...))) infinite times.

Comment: A solution to $\sin(\cos(\tan(x)))=x$, it seems very unlikely a 'closed form' solution will exist imo.

Comment: In that case I'm confused by the "as $x$ tends to 0" part.  We can't actually have infinitely many function applications, we can only apply the function $n$ times and take the limit as $n \to \infty$.  So I assumed that was the limit you are talking about.  But are we also taking the limit as $x \to 0$?

Comment: Let $f=\sin \circ \cos \tan$ and given $n\in \Bbb N$ let $f^{n+1}(x):=f(f^n(x))$ with $f^1(x)=f(x)$, for all $x\in \Bbb R$. The OP seems to be looking for $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\left(f^n(0)\right)$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Sorry, I meant for x = 0.

Comment: @GitGud That's what I thought at first, but in that case why not just let $x = 0$ rather than taking the limit as $x \to 0$?  And if we are letting both $x$ and $n$ vary, then the order in which we take the limit might matter.

Comment: @TrevorWilson It's possible the OP is just playing around and doesn't have the necessarily mathematical rigour in him to formalize the problem as I did.

Comment: you could compute it to, say, 20 digits precision and feed WolframAlpha with it. Perhaps it suggests a meaningful analytical expression worth to be investigated?

Comment: @GitGud That hurt, but you are right :(

Comment: @Prometheus It's not meant to be offensive. That comes with experience, it's nothing to feel bad about.

Comment: @Prometheus Okay. In that case I think Ethan is probably right.  The limit as $n \to \infty$ will be a fixed point of the function, that is, a solution of $\sin(\cos(\tan(x))) = x$, and there is probably no way to express solutions to this equation in closed form.

Comment: The question really is whether $x_{n+1} = \sin(\cos(\tan (x_n)))$ converges. And if it does, then whether the convergence and particular limit value depends on the initial value $x_1$.

Comment: Pari/GP gives using *"x0=0;for(k=1,1000,x0=sin(cos(tan(x0))));x0"* the result computed with internal 200 digits and displayed to 20 digits precision as $  0.65706820505108396697 $. Try www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.65706820505108396697

Comment: @user2566092 That is _a_ question, but the OP was asking about the case where the initial value is $0$, and also asking about _what_ it converges to (if it really does converge.)

Comment: @TrevorWilson For increasing number of the said blocks, the graph of the function seems to 'flatten' remaining more or less close to 0.7 for all x.

Comment: The limit for $x$ part is spurious. Start with any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the sequences $f^n(x)$ always converges to same limit ( the unique fixed point determined by the equation $f(x) = x$ )

Comment: @TrevorWilson Well it was originally phrased as the limit as $x \to 0$, so I think my interpretation would be the right way to go in that case. At any rate, my phrasing of the question seems to be the most mathematically complete way of approaching the problem, even if it's somewhat a generalization of the problem originally posed.

Comment: @achillehui There could be cycles for infinitely many starting conditions $x_1$, unless something is proved about the fixed point equation. Like it has to be a contraction or something.

Comment: @user2566092, after 2 iterations, $f^{\circ 2}$ map every $x$ into the interval $[0,1]$. On $[0,1]$, $f$ is strictly monotonic decreasing. This implies $f^{\circ 2}$ is strictly monotonic increasing and hence for any $x \in [0,1]$, the even and odd subsequences $f^{\circ 2n}(x)$ and $f^{\circ 2n+1}(x)$ are monotonic in $n$. Since both of them are bounded and $f^{\circ 2}$ is continuous, they converge to a fix point of $f^{\circ 2}$. If one plot $f^{\circ 2}$ over $[0,1]$, it has a unique fixed point and hence both the even and odd subsequences converge to that unique fixed point...

Comment: @achillehui You should post this as an answer, it at least answers the question as to whether the fixed point exists. Approximations can then be obtained by iteration, or perhaps Newton's method. And it shows that it suffices to solve $\sin \cos \tan x = x$, even if no analytic solution is known.

Answer (score 3):

As requested, this is a comment turned answer which shows why the sequences always 
converges and independent of initial starting value of $x$.

Let $f(x) = \sin(\cos(\tan(x)))$.

After one iteration, it is clear $f$ maps every $x$ into
some value inside the interval $[-1,1]$.
If one plot $f(x)$ over $[-1,1]$, one find:

1. $f( [-1, 1] ) \subset [0,1]$.
2. $f(x)$ is strictly monotonic decreasing over $[0,1]$.

The $1^{st}$ observation tells us we only need to study the behavior of $f^{\circ n}(x)$
for $x \in [0,1]$.

The $2^{nd}$ observation tell us $f^{\circ 2} = f \circ f$ is strictly monotonic
increasing over $[0,1]$. This implies for any $x \in [0,1]$, the even and odd sub-sequences
$f^{\circ 2n}(x)$ and $f^{\circ 2n+1}(x)$ are monotonic in $n$. Since both of them are
bounded by $0$ and $1$ and $f^{\circ 2}$ is continuous, these two sub-sequences converge
to some fixed points of $f^{\circ 2}$.

If one make another plot of $f^{\circ 2}$ over $[0,1]$, one will notice $f^{\circ 2}$ has
a unique fixed point (the same one as the fixed point of $f$). This implies the limit of the even and odd sub-sequences coincides and equal to the unique fixed point of $f$.

From this, we can conclude:

Start from any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the sequence $f^{\circ n}(x)$ always converges to
a unique $y \in [0,1]$ which satisfies the equation $y = f(y) = \sin(\cos(\tan y)))$.